# How can i obtain a string between two specific strings using regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angularjs

I have a string like this,

```
green open calldetails  1 0 4 0 10.7kb 10.7kb 
green open stocksummary 1 0 3 0  8.6kb  8.6kb
```

I need to obtain Stocksummary and calldetails from this.
This is what i have tried using regex,

```
var result = string.match(/(?:open )(.+)(?:1)/)[1];
```

Here is my full function:

```
routerApp.controller("elasticindex",function($scope,es){
  es.cat.indices("b",function(r,q){
   String St = string.match(/(?:open )(.+)(?:1)/)[1];
  console.log(r,q);
});
});
```

**Desired Output:**

```
calldetails
stocksummary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This non-greedy (lazy) regex should work instead:

```
/open +(.+?) +1/
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO5kJ7/2)

```
var result = string.match(/open +(.+?) +1/)[1];
```

Or safe approach:

```
var result = (string.match(/open +(.+?) +1/) || ['', ''])[1];
```

**Code:**

```
var re = /open +(.+?) +1/g,
    matches = [],
    input = "green open calldetails 1 0 4 0 10.7kb 10.7kb green open stocksummary 1 0 3 0 8.6kb 8.6kb";
while (match = re.exec(input)) matches.push(match[1]);
console.log(matches);
```

#### [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b39z8n7h/)

Comment: it gives  open stocksummary 1

Comment: Problem was `g` flag, it is fixed now. Check my updated version.

Comment: it works fine, i am having a small issue. since it is a string, "green open calldetails  1 0 4 0 10.7kb 10.7kb 
green open stocksummary 1 0 3 0  8.6kb  8.6kb" how can i get indexes individualy. how can i get calldetails and stocksummary?